# why i'm not able read whole excel sheet to Datatable varialbe ( dtExcelData)

Tags: c#, asp.net

[enter image description here][1]

This is the image code where some data get missing while reading  excel sheet to datatable variable
(dtExcelData).
[1]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHqkg.png)

Comment: Hello Prajwal

Could you explain better what's going on?

Comment: please include code, error messages, and other _text-based_ information ***as text***, not as screenshot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if you want to import to DataGridView

```
        OleDbConnection theConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + txtFileName.Text + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\"");
        theConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter theDataAdaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from[Sheet1$]", theConnection);
        DataSet theSD = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        theDataAdaptor.Fill(dt);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

[image]

Comment: Not able to read the data from an Excel sheet  into a DataTable there are 33 column in my excel sheet but only 31 column getting read

Comment: yes this is happening with me in some coloumn half data getting inserted and some data not  inserting in datatable variable

Comment: if you refer to data that looks like 1.. this is because the column width is not set and the empty cells in DataGridView are empty cells in Excel file

Comment: in Excel file all cells are filled .In excel i have mobile number column all number are 10 digits but when reading to datatable variable some of mobile no. not getting inserted

Comment: can you show as 2 rows from the excel file 1 that is geting inserted and 1 that is not geting inserted?